# jQuery works if I refresh the page, but not on original load. Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension. It has a browser action. When that is clicked, a javascript file gets run. That file creates a new tab. In that tab, there are divs. I'm trying to manipulate their content.
To rephrase the question: How can I get it to work on the first time the button is clicked. (Note: if I click the button and then refresh the page, that version of the code will work until I change the code and then refresh the page again.)

From Chrome's help pages, I found:

> // Add event listeners once the DOM has fully loaded by listening for the
>   // `DOMContentLoaded` event on the document, and adding your listeners to
>   // specific elements when it triggers.
>   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
>    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
>   });

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Javascript file in manifest:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

//This is to put the manager one tab to the right
var myIndex = tab.index;
chrome.tabs.create({index : myIndex + 1, url: "newTab.html"});
```

newTab.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functionality02.js"></script>
<html><head>
<title>Title</title>

</head><body>
<div id='try'></div>

</body></html>
```

functionality02.js

```
function letsTryThis2(){

$("#try").append("<div>Some Content.</div>");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', letsTryThis2);
```

Comment: Does `document.ready` not work in an extension? What about the load event instead of DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: Load didn't work. I don't think document.ready would either. They specifically mentioned DOMContentLoaded. I'll add it above.

Comment: so wait, when you refresh the page, what happens now?  not clear.... ;) Consider a bulleted step by step of what you do to see the issue...

Comment: OK. So with the original code above. I'll edit what goes into the div. (Where "Some Content" is.) So if I click the button and then the refresh button. I'll get whatever I put in the appended div. If I close that (but the window is still open), edit what's in the appended div, I'll get the original content if I click the button again. (Note: I did refresh the background page.) If I want to see the new content I'll have to refresh the page after clicking the button.

Comment: Ok, so you're modifying the code and not seeing changes? That's normal. The script is embedded on the page when you load it. What you're editing is the copy that gets loaded. Well, to reload that modified copy, you have to reload the page. Consider that your users will never face this issue, unless they're Chrome hackers and play around with the code, in which case, they probably know to refresh the page. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Extensions are loaded into the browser, just like how JavaScript on a Web site is loaded onto the page. If you change the source code, you need to reload the app at worst and refresh the page at best.

Chrome Extensions weren't designed for real time changes, as this is inefficient and is something that only you, the developer, would be affected by.

The behavior you're seeing is perfectly normal. The script is embedded on the page when you load it. To reload that modified source, you have to reload the page so it gets applied again. Consider that your users will never face this issue, unless they're Chrome hackers and play around with the code, in which case, they probably know to refresh the page. ;)

Comment: Yes! Removing the extension and loading it again wouldn't show the updates, but putting it in a new folder showed the changes. Thanks! :)

Comment: You know, I'm working on an extension right now, and every now and then it gets "stuck" or "super-cached" and I have to restart the darn browser. I'm sure it's a fluke... Glad you got it working. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
function letsTryThis2(){
    $("#try").append("<div>Some Content.</div>");
}
$(window).load(function () {
  letsTryThis2();
});
```

**EDIT:**
as a (BAD) alternative to my comment,
you might try this:

```
    function letsTryThis2(){
        $("#try").append("<div>Some Content.</div>");
    }
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        letsTryThis2();
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: btw: it might happen that JQuery is not loaded when you try to run your function. you should wait for JQuery to load, or combine the two so you will be sure it is loaded. your `functionality02.js` script might be loaded BEFORE JQuery does.

Comment: You should include that in your answer, not the comments. Comments are intended to ask for clarification or offer tips to improve an answer. Good luck!

Comment: The first one had the same problem as my original. The second - the content never came up. Looking into checking to see if jquery is loaded.

Comment: OK. I added what was in functionality02.js to the bottom of jquery and I still had that problem.

Comment: you still have to add my first code to the JQuery file to make it work. so when the document is ready, and everything is loaded, only then the function should be run.